# For value falls within a range get corresponding value

Tags: awk, search, array

I am thinking to use awk to search a value from input file in a reference file and get a corresponding value from reference file.

Both reference and input files can be sorted based on $3 and $2 correspondingly (I guess it will be easier if they sorted).
Reference File:

```
ID3  A    16553824    16561652    -1
ID4  A    22629640    22630440    -1
ID1  A    26607738    26607962    -1
ID2  A    28571020    28571736    -1
```

Input File:

```
A 16553900 16554000 -1
A 26607800 26607900 -1
A 28571050 28571100 -1
```

I want to compare input$2 to reference$3 and $4. If reference$3 < input$2 < reference$3, corresponding row will be assigned reference$1 in input$5. So it will look like:

Desired Output:

```
A 16553900 16554000 -1 ID1
A 26607800 26607900 -1 ID3
A 28571050 28571100 -1 ID4
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks to me like your desired output is wrong.

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {min[$1]=$3; max[$1]=$4; next}
    {
        for (id in min) 
            if (min[id] < $2 && $2 < max[id]) {
                print $0, id
                break
            }
    }
' reference input
```

```
A 16553900 16554000 -1 ID3
A 26607800 26607900 -1 ID1
A 28571050 28571100 -1 ID2
```

Comment: Yes, thank, Your output is correct. I tried the code, but error is for (id in min) if (min[id]<$2) {print$0, id >>>  break <<< }}. I tried to move the break to other places but I got more than 1 id for each input entry...